# How to extend Scala Maps: implementing get and iterator

Tags: scala, dictionary, collections

I'm making a custom SparseMatrix in Scala as an exercise. I want to do this by extending the immutable map. The functionality should be something like this:

```
> val x = SparseMatrix(Array(1,2,3), .8)
x: SparseMatrix[Float] = SparseMatrix(Array(1,2,3) -> .8)
> x(Array(1,2,3))
res1: Float = .8
> x(Array(3,3,3))
res2: Float = 0
```

However, I cannot figure out how to implement the required `get` and `iterator` methods. E.g.

```
class SparseMatrix[T <: Numeric[T]]
    extends immutable.MapLike[Array[Int], T, SparseMatrix[T]]
    with immutable.DefaultMap[Array[Int], T]{

  def iterator: Iterator[(Array[Int], T)] = ???

  def get(key: Array[Int]): Option[T] = ???

  // some other custom methods...
}
```

I've looked at the class definitions of the various maps inside of the collections library, and I cant figure out how they work. The only time I can find these implemented is inside of the `scala.collection.immutable.Map` companion object:

```
  class Map1[K, +V](key1: K, value1: V) extends AbstractMap[K, V] with Map[K, V] with Serializable {
    override def size = 1
    override def apply(key: K) = if (key == key1) value1 else throw new NoSuchElementException("key not found: " + key)
    override def contains(key: K) = key == key1
    def get(key: K): Option[V] =
      if (key == key1) Some(value1) else None
    def iterator = Iterator((key1, value1))
    override def updated [V1 >: V] (key: K, value: V1): Map[K, V1] =
      if (key == key1) new Map1(key1, value)
      else new Map2(key1, value1, key, value)
    def + [V1 >: V](kv: (K, V1)): Map[K, V1] = updated(kv._1, kv._2)
    def - (key: K): Map[K, V] =
      if (key == key1) Map.empty else this
    override def foreach[U](f: ((K, V)) => U): Unit = {
      f((key1, value1))
    }
  }
```

However, this only seems to make sense because the keys and values are being explicitly passed as arguments. This doesn't work for me as I want to be able to pass a variable number of arguments. At no point is there a generic implementation of `get` or `iterator` (I looked extensively). Where the default implementation of `Map` actually gets its `get`/`iterator` methods is completely mysterious. (Furthermore, why there are implementations of `Map1 ... Map4` inside of `scala.collection.immutable.Map` is also unknown.)

How can I implement `get` and `iterator` such that I can replicate the basic functionality of a map? Bonus: how the heck does the generic `Map` get its builtin `get` and `iterator` when they are explicitly undefined?

Note: simply using `super` as is done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34721211/how-to-extend-mutable-map-in-scala) does not work as I get the following error :

```
Error:(15, 60) method iterator in trait MapLike is accessed from super. It may not be abstract unless it is overridden by a member declared `abstract' and `override'
  override def iterator: Iterator[(Array[Int], T)] = super.iterator
```

Comment: How do you store the data internally inside your `SparseMatrix`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I haven't implemented that. Storing data internally didn't show up in the source code, If its necessary, I'm open to whatever you think is best.

Comment: If you'll dig into the implementation of `get0` in `HashTrieMap`, you'll see that it queries the internal array storing the data. You'll need to do something similar in your data structure.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Thanks for the tip!